# Select a option when attribute is greater than value input - Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a input and a select option use select2 :

```
<input type="number" id ="area"/>
<select id ="demo">
  <option data-area = "100">100 area</option>
  <option data-area = "150">150 area</option>
  <option data-area = "200">200 area</option>
  <option data-area = "230">230 area</option>
</select>
```

```js
var area = $('#area').val();

if (area) {
  $('select#demo').filter(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-area') > compare) {
      alert(1);
    } else {
      alert(2);
    }
  });
}
```

When user type number (example: 130), Expected result: Auto select this option

```
<option data-area = "150">150 area</option>
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/1fh4jmsy/6/ but it doesn't work.

Comment: when are you triggering the function? onKeyup or onChange

Comment: i use onChange bro.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `change` event to select the desired value.
The `return false` in the foreach function (loop) will act as a `break` keyword

```
$('#area').change(function(){
    var area = $('#area').val();
    $('select#demo option').each(function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).attr('data-area')) >= parseInt(area) ){
        $('select#demo').val($(this).val());
      return false;
    }
  })
})
```

Refer [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/1fh4jmsy/37/)

Comment: @chinhnguyen, are you sure `$('select#demo').val($(this).val());` this line is going to select value from dropdown?

Comment: Yes, `$(this)` is the current drop-down value on which the loop is being performed

Comment: @Taleeb, if you see dropdown value is not just integer but with word `area` and it has attribute `data-area` which is not a value for option.

Comment: Right. That's why we are using `data-attribute` to do the comparison. Once we have determined that the current `option` is to be selected, we are selecting the `current option` (which is `$(this)`). Of course, this is assuming that value entered in `#area` is integer and that the value in drop-down list is in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you need to hook to the `input` event of the textbox so that you can update the selection as the user types. Then you can use `filter()` to find the `option` elements with a `data-area` larger than the provided value, before using `prop()` to select the first of those:

```js
$('#area').on('input', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();

  $('#demo option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('area') >= parseInt(val, 10);
  }).first().prop('selected', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="area" />

<select id="demo">
  <option data-area="100">100 area</option>
  <option data-area="150">150 area</option>
  <option data-area="200">200 area</option>
  <option data-area="230">230 area</option>
</select>
```

Note that this logic assumes that the `option` values are always in ascending order.

Comment: Thank for answer my question, you should use ' >= ' . Hava a nice day bro

Comment: In your example fiddle in the question you use `>` so I copied that.

Comment: Sr, my bad.  Thank again.

Comment: @chinhnguyen, looks like you are suggesting improvements to SO users which you can do it on yourself and you have accepted answer which even does not work properly. Why is that so?